# How to fix error "ValueError: The condensed distance matrix must contain only finite values." for hierarchical clustering with Yule metric in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

I am currently trying to create a hierarchical clustering using seaborn.
My code for this is currently

```
  clustermap = sns.clustermap(df, metric='yule', col_cluster=True,
                                        figsize=(7, 5))
```

where my dataframs looks like 10 row-names (strings) and a couple thousand col-names (0-3000 numeric ascending) with all other values being 0 or 1.

When I try this with euclidean and other metrics, I have no issues. However when trying this with the Yule distance I get "ValueError: The condensed distance matrix must contain only finite values.".

I checked that there were no NA or blank data values in df and tried df.replace(np.nan, 0) to double check this was not this issue.
Additionally I could not find any values other than 0 or 1 in the dataframe.
A small example of what's going on is below:

```
    # initialize list of lists
    data = [[1,0,0,0,0,0], [ 1,0,1,1,0,1], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0], [ 0,0,1,0,1,0]]

    # Create the pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[ 'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'])
    df = df.transpose()
    print(df)

    clustermap = sns.clustermap(df, metric='yule', col_cluster=True, figsize=(8, 6))
    
    plt.show()
```

Is there some check that I am missing specific to this metric? How can I fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm unclear what the goal is, but for the provided metric the underlying [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy-spatial-distance-pdist) produces `pdist(df, 'yule')` -> `[nan  2.  0.  2.  0. nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  2.]` Which are the `nan` values that cannot be graphed.

Comment: My goal was to see if there was a hierarchical structure between the col1-#s  and if there was a hierarchical structure between the rows as well. Do you know why the nan values occur + how to prevent them? Looking at the documentation it seems like the only constraint for using the Yule distance is that the values should be boolean arrays (which in this case the rows/cols are) but my guess is it's coming from rows/cols that are all 0 resulting in dividing by 0. However I'm not sure how to get around this issue when calculating the distance between the rows/cols.